# How to see if a specific formGroup in a formArray is valid

Tags: angular

I have a formArray and I want to check each individual formGroup to see if that specific group is valid or not (so I can then have specific function called on the specific groups that are valid and not on the groups that are invalid).

When I do `<div>Form Group Valid?: {{roundInputs.get('{{roundCount}}')?.valid}}</div>` it doesn't return false or true (where roundCount is the index in the ngFor encompassing everything).  However if I do `<div>Form Group Valid?: {{roundInputs.get('0')?.valid}}</div>` where 0 is the index then it returns true/false (or replace 0 with whatever index and it works all the same).

My thought is that the index is a number and the `roundInputs.get()` is looking for a string and the interpolation is using a number?  If that's the case my next thought is maybe I need to create a custom pipe that takes in a number and converts it to a string?

If anyone has any ideas or a better suggestion than a custom pipe it would be much appreciated.  I am a little surprised that Angular doesn't already have a pipe that transforms a number to a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in

```
<div>Form Group Valid?: {{roundInputs.get('{{roundCount}}')?.valid}}</div>
```

You're sending `'{{roundCount}}'` as a literal string so the get doesn't find the index.

As a workaround you can use

```
<div>Form Group Valid?: {{roundInputs.get(`${roundCount}`)?.valid}}</div>
```

or

```
<div>Form Group Valid?: {{roundInputs.get(roundCount + '')?.valid}}</div>
```

Comment: This works but when I try to call a function to do a calculation (if the form group is valid) I am getting this error:'ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: ''. Current value: '6'.'  I googled it and it appears to have to do with Angular's change detection.  Also, I would have thought the first scenario with `${roundCount}` would work but I was getting a parse error in VS Code (Parser Error: Unexpected token Lexer Error: Unexpected character [`] at column 17 in expression)

Answer (score 0):

When pushing FormGroup into FormArray, you need to make it mandatory. Angular checks and updates form array automatically. But if you want to do manually

1. First, get `roundInputs` as form array via getter

```
get getRoundInputs() {
        return this.roundInputs as FormArray;
    }
```

2. Then iterate over the array

```
this.roundInputs.controls.forEach((control) => {
//cast control as Form Group
});
```

This will give type safe form group.